# Change file names with find and iconv

Tags: bash, iconv

I've tried to change filenames using following script:

find dir/ -type f -exec mv {} $(echo {} | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT ) \;

Why doesn't it work? I mean when I have a file with character like 'ą' it should convert it to 'a'.

```
$ echo ążźćó | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
azzco
```

why does it not work in find -exec?

```
$ find dir/ -type f -exec mv {} $(echo {} | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT ) \;
mv: `dir/zią' and `dir/zią' are the same file
```

I get the same results using xargs:

```
$ find dir/ -type f | xargs -I{} echo {} | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
dir/zia
```

but:

```
$ find dir/ -type f | xargs -I{} mv {} $(echo {} | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT)
mv: `dir/zią' and `dir/zią' are the same file
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with using `$()` in this way is that the subshell executes *prior* to executing the `find` command, and not as part of `-exec`.  You can do it, but you'll need to invoke bash.  Something like:

```
find dir/ -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< $1)"' -- {} \;
```

Keep in mind this will also translit any special chars in directory names as well, which may cause the `mv` to fail.  If you only want to translit the filename, then you could:

```
find dir/ -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}/$(iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< ${1##*/})"' -- {} \;
```

which split the directory portion off and only translits the file name.

Comment: that's exactly what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< $1) -- beware $1 is not quoted here and multiple spaces will be stripped! ex. "a{space}{space}b" will become "a{space}b". to get around this you can use echo -n with a pipe instead of a herestring

Answer (score 0):

I don't know iconv that well, but

```
 echo ... | iconv ....
```

is fine for text strings, but if you want you use a filename, certainly  you need to specify the file on the right-hand-side of the iconv command line, i.e.

```
 ls *.files | xargs -I{}  iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT {}
```

right?

As for moving (`mv`) a file, you have make sure that the source filename is different from the target filename. It's not clear from you post what you want the target filename to be. If `iconv` can modify files in-place AND you don't care to keep the original, then I would expect the xargs I provide above should solve your problem.

OR are you saying that the actual filenames contains characters that you want to process with `iconv`. It might help to edit your post to include sample filenames, before and after iconv processing. Something like this?

```
find dir/ -type f -exec mv {} $(echo {}.fix | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT ) \;
```

For filenames that don't get modified by `iconv`, you have to have a way to make the name separate from the original filename. So this would be followed by an `/bin/rm {}` step.

OR see this post [How to recursively convert all filenames in folder subtree from UTF-8 to ASCII in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929441/how-to-recursively-convert-all-filenames-in-folder-subtree-from-utf-8-to-ascii-i) .

I hope this helps.

Comment: @wisent : I think I've completed edits to my post. Good luck.

Comment: actually I was inspired by that post :) I just wanted to do it for learning purpose. @FatalError provided the exact solution for my problem, but thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "DO" ] ; then
 if [ "$2" != "$3" ]; then
  mv "$2" "$3";
 fi
else
 find dir/ -type f -exec "bash" $0 "DO" {} $(echo {} | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT )  \;
fi
```