# Is there an automated way to change the encoding of the source files of a project?

Tags: jsp, encoding

I need to switch the encoding of the source files in a full java project. Currently it is configured as cp-1252 and I need it to be utf-8. However, there are LOTS of `.java, .css, .js, .jsp, .jspf, .properties, .you-name-it` and doing this by hand on say notepad or whatever is VERY tedious. Is there an automated way to do this? I tried to make a project out of the existing one, but it didn't work (not that I was very hopeful anyway).

I need something that makes the same I would do by hand:

- Open the file in a text editor
- "Save as" -- change the encoding property
- Repeat

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) tool, combined with a short shell script or perhaps a `find` call. Builds exist for Linuxes and Windows (see, for example, links on [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm)). Likely for other OSes as well.

Edit: See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930484/change-file-names-with-find-and-iconv).

Comment: I need it for windows. I will try this tomorrow. Need to look on how to make that script, I'm not currently a command línea guy :). Do you know if files won't get corrupted in any way, like messing with code indentation?

Comment: @Roger The result of a file will be garbage if the original file is not encoded in Windows-1252, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can put into a string the content of a file encoded in cp-1252 this way:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
String text = new Scanner(inputStream, "cp-1252").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
inputStream.close();
```

Then you can write the string `text` to a file encoded using utf-8 this way:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,  "utf-8");
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
bufferedWriter.append(text);
bufferedWriter.close();
```

To automate that process, you can create a method from the code above and call it for each file found using java [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method (I would make a backup before, though).

Comment: Cool, I was hoping to not re-invent the wheel (specially an already tested wheel), i.e. a built tool. I will accept the answer if there isn't such thing. Thanks!