# Only list files; iconv and directories?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, ls, iconv

I want to convert the coding of some csv-files with `iconv`. It has to be a script so I am working with `while; do done`. The script lists every item in a specific directory and converts them into another coding (utf-8).

Currently, my script lists EVERY item, including directories... So here are my questions

1. Does `iconv` has a problem with directories or does it ignore them?
2. And if there is a problem, how can I only list/search only for files?

I tried [How to list only files in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574794/608639) a `***./***` at the beginning of every item and that's kinda annoying (and my program doesn't like it, too).

Another possibility is `ls -p | grep -v /` but this would also affect files with ***/*** in the name, wouldn't it?

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

---

Here is the code:

```
for item in $(ls directory/); do
   FileName=$item
   iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" FileName -o FileName
done
```

Yea, i know, the input and output file cannot be the same^^

Comment: First, *do not parse the output of `ls`.* Second... how come your title mentions a good approach totally absent from your question? (Links don't really count...)

Comment: Plus, as far as I can see iconv does not *have* an option `-o`...

Comment: Sorry, u are right. I do have a problem with find . -maxdepth 1 -type f , but thats not the main one. I edited the title.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9930780/60281) showing what you can do with `find ... -exec`. That should always be the preferred route, because it doesn't balk at things like spaces or other funny things like newlines in the filename.

Comment: "Plus, as far as I can see iconv does not have an option " Well ok, but I used it with this options and it works perfectly and as expected. The only problem is that I have to feed this command with a list of csv-files...

Comment: Generally speaking, posting the exact problem you have with *one* approach (preferrably, the `find ... -exec` based one) and asking about that would be the better question. Right now you're asking "can you write an solution for me?", and that is usually not a good thing. -- You say your program "doesn't like the `./` at the beginning". What do you mean, "doesn't like"?

Comment: It seems like I expressed it badly :/ to be clear; I do note want and need a "write a solution for me"... I have a php-file working with those results and the ./ are annoying. Yea, I can cut it, but maybe there is an answer which is more elegant. The main problem is solved, iconv does NOT have a prolem with directories.

Comment: What "results" does the PHP script pick up? The filenames? I thought these are processed by `iconv`? If you need the *filenames themselves* without the leading `./`, try `find . -maxdepth 1 -type 1 -printf "%f"`. Caveats regarding whitespace in filenames applies.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the existing question that you referenced, Why don't you just remove the first 2 characters i.e. `./`?

```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c 3-
```

Edit: I agree with @DevSolar about the space-based problem in the for-loop. While I think that his solution is better for this problem, I just want to give an alternative way to get out of the space-based for-loop issue.

```
   OLD_IFS=$IFS
   IFS=$'\n'
   for item in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c 3-); do
   FileName=$item
   iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" FileName -o FileName
   done
   IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Comment: @DevSolar, Can you give an example  of a file name where it breaks?

Comment: hm well yea that would be a possiblity and I guess, I'm gonna do it like that. I just don't rly like it to hardcode a cut after a specfic amount of characters.... It seems so error-prone. Thank you :)

Comment: Depends on what he feeds the result of that command to. `for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c 3-); do echo $file; done` with filename "foo bar.txt" gives one "foo", one "bar.txt", and two "file not found" when you attempt any operation on those "files". ;-)

Comment: @Telvanis: Note my comment on using `-printf "%f"` if you want *just* the filename. Generally speaking, *do* read `man find`. That tool can do much more for you than you think, and beats virtually all other attempts at iterating over a set of files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` directly:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" $1 > $1.converted && mv $1.converted $1' -- {} \;
```

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` finds all files in the working directory
- `-exec ...` executes a command on each such file (including correct handling of e.g. spaces or newlines in the filename)
- `bash -c '...'` executes the command in `'...'` in a subshell (easier to do the subsequent steps, involving multiple expansions of the filename, this way)
- `--` terminates option processing, and treats anything after the `--` as arguments to the call.
- `{}` is replaced by `find` with the file name(s) found
- `$1` in the bash command is replaced with the first (and only) argument, which is the `{}` replaced by the filename (see above)
- `\;` tells `find` where the `-exec`'ed command ends.

Comment: Thank you for the effort